# Use JAXB to marshall bean in the service layer

Tags: jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I use Jersey with JAXB to convert my response to XML. I have several methods that consume XML from the Request Body. I can specify the bean as a parameter to the method being called and JAXB will be used to automatically transform the request body data to that bean, or fail if it's not compatible.

This works great for the majority of all my cases, and I have not had the need to write a MessageBodyReader or MessageBodyWriter to handle the transformation to and from. I have this one instance where I need the request body to be mapped to the bean, but I also need the original XML that was in the body of the request. I need to store that in the DB.

I've tried getting to the request body through the HttpContext, and can't figure out how - I just see the header values and URI values. I tried through the HTTPServletContext as well ending in the same result.

Is there a way to capture the request body as it is before it's transformed or after? Will I need to create a MessageBodyReader to handle this case? It seemed like those were used to map the contents to a bean, which I already have functioning, so I didn't think that was the solution. But, perhaps in the MessageBodyReader I can put the request body into some variable and pass it along while still transforming the data to the beans. That still seems kind of more work than is needed. I would think I could get to the body through the request somehow.

**Update:**
I tried getting the body from ContainerRequest object using the getEntity method.

```
    String xmlString = request.getEntity(String.class);
```

And, that worked great. The request body is captured in that property and I can add it to the request properties to access later in the resource, etc. The problem is, and I think it's because the entity is a stream, it clears out the body. So by the time the jaxb mapping to the beans happen, there is nothing to transform and I'm given a bad request response.

That didn't work but I wanted to throw it out there as a possibility if someone could get it working better.

Here is what I ended up doing, and it would be nice to not have to do it this way. I'm basically marshalling what was unmarshalled, in my service class.

```
    final StringWriter st = new StringWriter();
try
{

    final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(full.classpath.and.classname.of.root.bean);
    final Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.marshal(unmarshalled object, st);
} catch (final JAXBException je)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    je.printStackTrace();
}
final String xml = st.toString();
```

So you can see - I basically take the object, the root bean that the body was unmarshalled to, and marshal it, giving the location of the annotated root bean to use in marhsalling.

It seems a bit redonkulous to have to marshal what was already unmarshalled, and if that is the response, maybe marshalled again on the way out. I would like a solution where I could grab a copy of the body before the unmarshalling happens. But in the meantime, this will have to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same scenario and ended with similar conclusions, except I do it the other way around by getting it as a String and then marshal manually to avoid unnecessary JAXB work, e.g.:

```
String xmlString = request.getEntity(String.class);
Reader sReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
return (T)jaxbCtx.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(sReader);
```

Comment: I like this approach because, as you say, it avoids unnecessary JAXB work. And that is the problem with my approach.